# Json response returning HTML in nodejs/react page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, get, fetch, react-fullstack

I'm new react and nodejs and full stack development in general. I'm trying to make a login page in nodejs/react/mysql. Right now, I'm just trying to do get request for the main login page. I think I'm struggling with connecting the front and backend and the moment.

Nodejs app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');



let connection = mysql.createConnection({
 //Connection is encrypted for security reasons. 
 host: '***********',
 user: '***********t',
 password: '***********',
 database: '***********'
});

 connection.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) {
 return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
 }

 console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
});



app.listen(3001, () => { console.log('running on port 3001'); });

app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.json()); a
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

 app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.send('respond with a resource'); });
```

componentDidMount() react code/fetch request:

```
  componentDidMount() {
  // GET request using fetch with error handling
  fetch('/')
     .then(async response => {
         const data = await response.text();
        // console.log(data);
            console.log('test',data);

        // check for error response
        if (!response.ok) {
            // get error message from body or default to response statusText
            const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        this.setState({ totalReactPackages: data.total })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: error.toString() });
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
    });
   }
```

My sql connection works fine, I think it's an issues connecting the front end and backend. Changing following line:.

```
    const data = await response.text();
```

to:

```
    const data = await response.json();
```

Returns the following error:

```
  There was an error! SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

This is the html it returns in the following screenshot:

[image]

Once I figure out how to connect the front end and backend the rest of the project should be easyish to do. The react UI work and my SQl connection works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you doing server rendering? if not then fetch url needs to be something like http://localhost:3001/ to connect to your express server

Comment: I don't see the difference between what the line of code was, and what it was changed to. You should probably also check `repsonse.ok` *before* trying to unpack the response text/json. Why are you mixing async/await and promise chaining?

Comment: Sorry typo. Should be fixed now

Comment: Does [Proxying API Requests in Development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) help you?

Answer (score 2):

You're currently fetching data from the primary site, not the Node.js site you've created.

You should change the `fetch` to:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001')
```

**Additional information**

The response you are sending from the backend isn't JSON:

```
res.send('respond with a resource');
```

To send JSON, you should use:

```
res.json({ message: "respond with a resource" });
```

Then you'll be able to use:

```
const data = await response.json();
```

And access the data via:

```
const message = data.message;
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error: There was an error! SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: If you use `const data = await response.text(); console.log(data);` what's the output?

Comment: Just more of that html.

Comment: Ok, that's the reason you're getting the error.  HTML can't be parsed as JSON.  You'll need to figure out where the HTML is coming from.  Did you post the actual node.js code or is that just an example?

Comment: I have a bunch of code thats commented out, but that should be all the nodejs code i believe.

Comment: Ok, I think you need to change the `fetch('/')` to `fetch('http://localhost:3001/')`.  The response you're getting is from the "regular" site running on 3000 (based on the screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked just by appending "Https://" to the beginning of the API url.

```
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${CITY_NAME}&appid=${API_KEY}`)
```

It took me days and 10s of articles/SO threads to figure out that when doing dev on your local machine the fetch request gets routed to local html document.